# Using multiple Aggregate FUNCTIONS with isNULL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, isnull

This is the working query that I have:

```
SUM(Billings)/SUM(MarketingCosts) AS ROI,
(SUM(Billings)-SUM(Refunds))/SUM(MarketingCosts) AS ROIExcluded
```

What I want to add is if ROIExcluded is NULL, then the value of ROI should be displayed in the ROIExcluded Column.

This is something that I was trying to do but didnt work.

```
ISNULL((SUM(Billings)-SUM(Refunds))/SUM(MarketingCosts) AS ROIExcluded, ROI)
```

But this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: You cannot use output column alias in another column expression. Use a copy of expression instead. You cannot use an alias in the middle of the expression, place it after the expression. You cannot have different column names in different rows for the same column. The task is unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much @Akina. It is working now.